# Filtar json data em php

Tags: php, json

Boas,
Eu gostaria de filtrar a data de um ficheiro json. A data que recebo é uma coisa assim do genero.

```
{
"max_new_quota": 21474836480,
"username": "username@domain.com",
"rl": {
    "value": "60",
    "frame": "h"
},
"is_relayed": 0,
"name": "User Name",
"active": "&#10003;",
"active_int": 1,
"domain": "domain.com",
"local_part": "username",
"quota": 3221225472,
"attributes": {
    "force_pw_update": "0",
    "tls_enforce_in": "1",
    "tls_enforce_out": "1",
    "sogo_access": "0",
    "mailbox_format": "maildir:",
    "quarantine_notification": "never"
},
"quota_used": 10448756,
"percent_in_use": 0,
"messages": 125,
"spam_aliases": 0,
"percent_class": "success"
}
```

Queria saber como posso filtar isto em php para por exemplo mostrar  a quota e a quota used e assim em diante.
Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É simples, utilize `json_decode` e passe no segundo parâmetro `true` para criar um `array` associativo desse [json](/questions/tagged/json), ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

$json = '{
"max_new_quota": 21474836480,
"username": "username@domain.com",
"rl": {
    "value": "60",
    "frame": "h"
},
"is_relayed": 0,
"name": "User Name",
"active": "&#10003;",
"active_int": 1,
"domain": "domain.com",
"local_part": "username",
"quota": 3221225472,
"attributes": {
    "force_pw_update": "0",
    "tls_enforce_in": "1",
    "tls_enforce_out": "1",
    "sogo_access": "0",
    "mailbox_format": "maildir:",
    "quarantine_notification": "never"
},
"quota_used": 10448756,
"percent_in_use": 0,
"messages": 125,
"spam_aliases": 0,
"percent_class": "success"
}';

// criando o array associativo
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// imprimindo os dados
echo $data['quota']; // saída quota
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $data['quota_used']; // saída quota_used
```

e assim por diante pode resgatar todos os itens se assim quiser.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo seu comentário já-me ajudou bastante.Gostaria só de saber como poderia obter os valores dentro de rl

Comment: @JoséMartins `$data['rl']['value']` e `$data['rl']['frame']`